# What's the differentiation of $2x(\frac{dx}{dt})$ with respect to the variable $t$? Is it $2(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+2x(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2})$?

Tags: derivatives

What's the differentiation of $2x\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$ with respect to the variable $t$?

Is it $$2\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+2x\left(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\right)?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(t) = 2 x(t) \frac{dx}{dt}(t)$.

By the product rule for differentiation we get

$$
\frac{dg}{dt}(t) = 2 \left(\frac{dx}{dt}(t)\right)^2 + 2x(t)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}(t)
$$

so yes you are correct!

Comment: ooh I wish I was! I need this for a physics question and if I put the values I get a wrong answer! But thanks for the help @DodoDuQuercy

Comment: Perhaps there is an error with the question?

Comment: @GeneralKenobi, is this the entire question? Do the values you're putting in have something to do with another part of the question that you haven't shown us?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen no this is not the entire question, and yes the values I'm putting in are related to another part of the question. If you wanna see that question, I've posted it on the physics stack exchange, and you can check it out there if you want.

Comment: @GeneralKenobi : That offer would be substantially improved by linking to that question on Physics.SE...

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule:

$\frac{d}{dt}(2x⋅\frac{dx}{dt})=\frac{d}{dt}(2x)⋅\frac{dx}{dt}+2x⋅\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt})=2⋅\frac{dx}{dt}⋅\frac{dx}{dt}+2x⋅\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+2x⋅\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

This seems to be the answer, as @DodoDuQuercy pointed out. Perhaps there is a mistake in your assignment?